# use loop for time variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

i want have a loop that circle between maximum time of 10-10-2016 and minimum 10-10-2016 and the column 'state' change value to 'i'. my column names is , 'time','bus_line','rate','date

```
SELECT * from list

where date='2016-10-10' and rate='101' and bud_id='1900'
order by  time
for i in min(time)..max(time) loop
if time'i'<time<time'i' + interval '2.6 minute'
then state = 'i'
raise  notice 'i is %' , i;
end loop;
```

Comment: times like 8:32:00

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide sample data

Comment: Is thit the same question as your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519845/use-the-function-for-in-pgadmin-for-time), or a different one? Delete the previous if it's not proper and edit this one to explain in more detail.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  I'm relatively sure you don't need a loop for that. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast time value to *the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC* with `extract(epoch from min(time))` and then iterate over them.